# How did Kirk identify Gorgan in "And the Children Shall Lead"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

In the Original Series episode "And the Children Shall Lead", before Gorgan appears a second time (at about time index 43:45 on Netflix), there is no mention of his name.

How did Kirk know the name of the entity? Did Kirk recognize the entity the first time he appears?

According to non-canon *Star Trek* material, Q and 0 brought Gorgan and other malevolent entities into the present dimension approximately one million years ago. This can be verified [here](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Gorgan). Perhaps the Federation database had records of his appearances before or was it possibly a previous encounter?

Comment: Kirk must have come across the information in some way off-screen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This appears to be an error in filming. In an [earlier draft script](http://www.orionpressfanzines.com/articles/and_the_children_shall_lead.htm), **Kirk was apparently told the creature's name in a deleted scene.**

> **KIRK:** (continuing) *Come—join us. You—must have a name.*
>
> **TOMMY:** (defiantly) *He is Gorgan. He is our friend—and he is all powerful.*

And in the episode's official novelisation (itself based on the final shooting script), we see that the beast has a tendency to introduce itself whenever referring to itself in the first person, **and does so in Kirk's presence.**

> “Remember how it was on Triacus? If they resist, so shall it be on the
> Enterprise. If you need me, call me, and **I, Gorgan,** will appear. We
> make ready for our new beginning on Marcos Twelve. We must not
> falter…
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Trek 12](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_12)</sup></sub>

---

Obviously in the final cut this name-check was missed out and not fixed in post-production.

Answer (score 2):

It is never directly shown how Kirk knew the creature's name. An early draft of the script [did include a deleted scene](http://www.orionpressfanzines.com/articles/and_the_children_shall_lead.htm) in which Kirk asked what the creature was called and was informed by Tommy that it was Gorgan, but in a bit of sloppy editing the scene in question occurred after Kirk already referred to it by name.